# Forwarding emails from a gmail alias

Tags: gmail

I have created an alias (nickname) for my gmail (example@mydomain.com) which I would like to use on my web site. I am trying to figure out how to forward emails coming to this alias (info@mydomain.com) to several other email addresses (ie example1@mydomain.com, example2@mydomain.com). Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "gmail alias"? Is this another email account that you are able to send "From" using gmail? Do you pick up example@mydomain.com via POP3 into your gmail account, or is it simply forwarded?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to do this by setting up a [filter](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6579&rd=1).

First, verify each address you wish to forward to in the settings via `Forwarding and POP/IMAP` > `Add a forwarding address`.

Then, as per Google's instructions, you should be able to create a filter based on the search

```
to:(example@mydomain.com)
```

Then select the option to forward email to your chosen address. You'll need to set up a filter for each address, since you can only forward to one address per filter.